# How to get row values between dates?

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc-5, sql-server-2014

I have a stored procedure that gets me a rows between a MinDate and MaxDate.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetFilteredDomainDetails]
    @Id bigint,
    @From datetime2,
    @To datetime2
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT 
        DomainId, [Date], DomainName, 
        ServerPerformance, DatabasePerformance, SoldTickets 
    FROM 
        DomainDetailDataHistory
    WHERE 
        DomainId = @Id AND Date >= @From AND date <=@To
    ORDER BY 
        date ASC
END
```

The thing is that I am calculating the amount of sold tickets between the rows:

```
    for (int i = databaseData.Count() - 1; i > 0; i--)
    {
        long soldtickets = databaseData[i].SoldTickets - databaseData[i - 1].SoldTickets;
        databaseData[i].SoldTickets = soldtickets < 0 ? databaseData[i].SoldTickets : soldtickets;
    }
```

The problem:

I have is that i need one extra row that is below mindate in order to get the right ticket calculations.

I could do this:

```
SELECT TOP 1  
    DomainId, [Date], DomainName, 
    ServerPerformance, DatabasePerformance, SoldTickets 
FROM
    DomainDetailDataHistory 
WHERE 
    [Date] > @From AND DomainId = @Id   
ORDER BY 
    date ASC
```

And receive this as a secondary select statement on the server.

However I feel that it is not a clean way to accomplish what I am looking for and I am curious if there is a better way?

Comment: I think sample data and desired results would help explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: I tried not including so much data since I felt that i could make myself clear in words alone. The simplicity of this is that I want to get rows between my min and max date but also JUST 1 row(latest) that is below my mindate. The practical way of accomplishing it is another matter.

I will add data aswell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking for something that could get me this in one select statment but realized that this will just be timeconsuming to figure it out so I vent with the following solution:

```
DECLARE @Temp TABLE(DomainId  bigint,[Date] datetime2,DomainName varchar(max), ServerPerformance bigint, DatabasePerformance bigint, SoldTickets bigint )

INSERT INTO @Temp
            SELECT TOP 1 DomainId, [Date],DomainName, ServerPerformance, DatabasePerformance, SoldTickets FROM DomainDetailDataHistory
            WHERE DomainId = @Id AND Date < @From 
            order by date DESC

SELECT * FROM @Temp

SELECT h.DomainId, h.[Date], h.DomainName, h.ServerPerformance, h.DatabasePerformance, h.SoldTickets 
FROM DomainDetailDataHistory h
JOIN @Temp T ON T.DomainId = h.DomainId
WHERE h.DomainId = @Id AND h.[Date] >= T.[Date] AND h.[date] <=@To
order by date asc
```

Answer (score -1):

You can modify your code like this for better execution`SELECT DomainId, [Date],DomainName, ServerPerformance, DatabasePerformance, SoldTickets FROM DomainDetailDataHistory
    WHERE DomainId = @Id AND Date between @From AND @To order by date asc`